# Java button creation not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

Here is my program.This program simply creates a frame using swings in java and create a grid first and adds button to that frame:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class one {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Container pane=frame.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,6));

        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[26];

        String  b[]={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
        for(int i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(b[i]);
            buttons[i].setSize(80, 80);
            buttons[i].setActionCommand(b[i]);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String choice = e.getActionCommand();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have clicked: "+choice);
                }
            });
            System.out.println("adding button\n");
            pane.add(buttons[i]);
        }

    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The program compiles fine.But the button creation i can see only one button that is "A" and rest of the buttons i am not able to see in the pane.

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: it just works fine and I could see all 26 buttons.

Comment: Your code works for me - which Java-Version are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce, I see all buttons (A-Z) on the pane.

Comment: Does this output message appear 26 times?

Comment: Btw, calling setSize() and using a LayoutManager (GridLayout) is conflicting (and usually the setSize() ends up ignored), so simply drop that call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that this seems to be a race condition and/or system dependent type issue, since it works for others. In any case, the [Javadoc for java.awt.Container.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) states:

> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore,
>   invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been
>   displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to
>   display the added component.

You should therefore call pane.validate() after you have added all components (or, as MadProgrammer says, execute the setVisible() call **after** you have added all your components).

Comment: Thanks :) In any case, I hope to get some feedback from the OP - it would be very interesting to see which of our suggestions actually fixed the issue

Comment: I got it work with both `invalidate` and `validate`, I would suggest you answer is more correct given the fact the `invalidate` has already being called by `add`

Answer (score 3):

There are, essentially two ways to fix this problem.

The first, is call `frame.setVisible(true)` AFTER you have completed adding the buttons to the `pane`.

The second is to call

```
pane.invalidate();
pane.repaint();
```

After you have added all the buttons to the `pane`

Comment: According to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) (assumed they are correct), invalidate() should not be necessary since this is what add() does implicitly (and what could be the cause for the issue)

Comment: @Andreas Your are right, but welcome to the world of "why didn't that work?", so often I find myself starting off with `repaint`, adding `invalidate` and in really weird cases, `revalidate` which just shouldn't be needed :P

Comment: Yes, *that* is not more than true :-)

Comment: @Andreas I guess I could call `validate` instead, but I've always had more luck with `invalidate`

Comment: *"The first, is call frame.setVisible(true) AFTER"*  I bet if that is done, the '2nd' point will not be needed.

Comment: @andrew absolutely, it's pick a solution night ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can see buttons(A-Z). I could not reproduce your problem.
[image]